# I would like to know how to execute asynchronous processing every 1000ms

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to execute asynchronous processing in each statement every 1000ms.

When the following code is executed, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" error is output from Google Maps API.
Since most objects are processed successfully, I guess it is in the limit of seconds (10 queries/sec).
And, it doesn't seem to communicate with Google Maps Servers every 1000ms.
Therefore, I want to prevent errors by coding to communicate with Google Maps Servers every 1000ms.

```
$.each(resp.records, function(i, value) {

  let distance = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      let distanceMatrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
      let originName = record['Address']['value'];
      let originPos = new google.maps.LatLng(record['Llatitude']['value'], record['Longitude']['value']);

      let destinationName = value['Address']['value'];
      let destinationPos = new google.maps.LatLng(value['Llatitude']['value'], value['Longitude']['value']);

      if (!isNull(value['Address']['value'])) {
        distanceMatrix.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [originPos, originName],
          destinations: [destinationName, destinationPos],
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status !== 'OK') {
            reject(status);
          } else {
            if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === 'OK') {
              resolve(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
            } else if (response.rows[0].elements[1].status === 'OK') {
              resolve(response.rows[0].elements[1].distance.value);
            } else if (response.rows[1].elements[0].status === 'OK') {
              resolve(response.rows[1].elements[0].distance.value);
            } else {
              resolve(response.rows[1].elements[1].distance.value);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

  distance.then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    if (results <= 1000) {
      array.push([value['$id']['value'], value['Address']['value']]);
    }

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` only runs the code once. Use `setInterval` to run every 1000 ms.

Comment: The following happens in your code: The loop runs x times, setTimeout delays all the elements at 1000ms, all elements wait for the same 1000ms, all setTimeouts fire at the same time. You can use `, 1000 * (i + 1)` to set a delay of 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, .... ms for the elements. However, I'd rewrite the code completely. An Observable seems to be the better tool here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following. This should loop through your `resp.records` array within 1000ms intervals (I assume it is an array, if not, get the object keys and iterate over the array of keys).

(EDIT: This should be better than creating n timers for each request.)

```
let i = 0;

let interval = setInterval(() => {

    if (i >= resp.records.length) {
        if (resp.records.length === 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    const value = resp.records[i];

    let distance = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        let distanceMatrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        let originName = record['Address']['value'];
        let originPos = new google.maps.LatLng(record['Llatitude']['value'], record['Longitude']['value']);

        let destinationName = value['Address']['value'];
        let destinationPos = new google.maps.LatLng(value['Llatitude']['value'], value['Longitude']['value']);

        if (!isNull(value['Address']['value'])) {
            distanceMatrix.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [originPos, originName],
                destinations: [destinationName, destinationPos],
                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status !== 'OK') {
                    reject(status);
                } else {
                    if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === 'OK') {
                        resolve(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
                    } else if (response.rows[0].elements[1].status === 'OK') {
                        resolve(response.rows[0].elements[1].distance.value);
                    } else if (response.rows[1].elements[0].status === 'OK') {
                        resolve(response.rows[1].elements[0].distance.value);
                    } else {
                        resolve(response.rows[1].elements[1].distance.value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

    distance.then(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        if (results <= 1000) {
            array.push([value['$id']['value'], value['Address']['value']]);
        }

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    i++;


}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have confirmed that it is completely functional.